# Change Superset ports in docker compose yaml

Tags: apache-superset

I'm trying superset on windows through "docker desktop", using docker compose.

Some errors were thrown because the ports needed (8080 and 8088) were already in use.

Can I solve this by solely editing the docker-compose.yml file or do I need to change other settings also? What do I need to change?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the port mappings in the ports section to use different host ports that are not in use like this:

```yaml
superset:
  image: apache/superset
  ports:
    - "8081:8080"
    - "8089:8088"
```

Then you can run it again with `docker-compose up`